# Why does the priest have a full bottle of wine in The Sopranos S01E05?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, the-sopranos

I was re-watching The Sopranos. In Season 1 Episode 5, With Carmela, the priest says that he has a communion kit because he went to see a (presumably dying) patient in the hospital (to give communion).

[image]

But the wine bottle is full. Is this a goof or was it intentional and means that the priest lied? (Or maybe something else?)

Comment: Maybe the patient died before he got to them? (Why would he lie, BTW?)

Comment: @Walt to get to shag Carmela? In the morning after he throws up he asks if they have done anything - so he sees such thing happening as a possibility. Didn't want to put this into main question to not to lead readers to this conclusion btw.

Comment: But how would the communion kit help him in any way? (The wine is only *sipped*)

Comment: @Walt You do have a point, so your answer would be that this is a goof and not an attempt to make Carmela start drinking that makes her more relaxed which then leads to other things?

Comment: Sure, or there's some negligible reason like the one I mentioned above. I could sum it up in an answer if you want, I'm just not expert on priesthood.

Comment: @Walt It would be somewhat awkward if you would be an expert :) Sure answer would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I doubt that Father Phil drove around with a communion kit to a clothing drive and then to Carmella on the off-chance that they have Communion for some reason and a sip of wine will get her in the mood. They drink wine anyway before that scene and do so casually, since Father Phil feels at home there and usually passive-aggressively helps himself to their amenities. He doesn't need to trick her like that.

So I think he was telling the truth, and the options as I see them are:

- This is a goof and the writers\production simply didn't think this through;
- The patient Father Phil was visiting either died or got better before he got there, so his services weren't needed after all;
- Father Phil refilled the decanter somehow. Maybe he has some extra sacramental wine in his car for emergencies. This is conjecture, though.

Comment: Of course, since points 2 and 3 happen in a fictitious atmosphere, the logic conclusion is the first point.